# Nuget Restore does not work via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, xamarin, nuget

I am building up a Jenkins environment for building Xamarin app projects.
I want to do a nuget restore at the start of the job by executing the command via powershell, but nuget can't find the referenced packages. It throws errors like:

```
WARNING: Unable to find version '2.9.0' of package 'ReactiveProperty'.
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.0.2' of package 'PCLStorage'.
WARNUNG: Unable to find version '2.3.0-beta2' of package 'Rx-Interfaces'.
...
```

When I do the nuget restore with my windows (admin) user in powershell, it just works fine and is copying all the referenced packages into the project.

I feel that this has something to do with permissions...

OS is Windows 10, Jenkins version is 2.19.1

Here is the full Jenkins log:

```
Gestartet durch Benutzer xxx
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Baue in Arbeitsbereich e:\jenkins_workspace\xxx
Updating xxx at revision '2016-11-11T11:24:47.469 +0100'
At revision 36612

No changes for xxx since the previous build
[xxx] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "&'C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson7328741479356255129.ps1'"
Restoring NuGet package PCLStorage.1.0.2.
Restoring NuGet package ReactiveProperty.2.9.0.
WARNUNG: Unable to find version '1.0.2' of package 'PCLStorage'.
WARNUNG: Unable to find version '2.9.0' of package 'ReactiveProperty'.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-Core.2.3.0-beta2.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-Interfaces.2.3.0-beta2.
WARNUNG: Unable to find version '2.3.0-beta2' of package 'Rx-Core'.
WARNUNG: Unable to find version '2.3.0-beta2' of package 'Rx-Interfaces'.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-Linq.2.3.0-beta2.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-Main.2.3.0-beta2.
WARNUNG: Unable to find version '2.3.0-beta2' of package 'Rx-Main'.
WARNUNG: Unable to find version '2.3.0-beta2' of package 'Rx-Linq'.
Restoring NuGet package Rx-PlatformServices.2.3.0-beta2.
Restoring NuGet package Serilog.1.5.7.
WARNUNG: Unable to find version '2.3.0-beta2' of package 'Rx-PlatformServices'.
...
...
...
Eine Ausnahme vom Typ "NuGet.CommandLineException" wurde ausgel”st.
Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Could you post the complete log from the Jenkins?

Comment: Hi, yes of course.
Unfortunately, there is no other error message than the whole list of failed packages.

Added the full log to the original question

Comment: What version of NuGet is being used? If it is NuGet v3 then it may be that user has no packages defined in their NuGet.Config file under their profile. NuGet v2 used to use nuget.org by default but I believe NuGet v3 will not add any sources by default.

Comment: Wow, thank you.
I downloaded NuGet 2.8.x and it works like a charm :)